# Estimates involving Schrodinger Equation

Tags: estimation, partial-differential-equations, strichartz-estimates

Estimates of the extension operator can be seen as estimates of the initial value problem for the evolution Schrodinger equation. If $u(x,t)=e^{it\Delta}u_0$ is the solution to the IVP:

$$i\partial_t u(x,t) + \Delta u(x,t)=0$$
$$u(x,0)=u_0$$

Then the following estimates hold:

$a)$ if $D^\gamma$ is the fractional derivative  $D^\gamma _x =\int e^{ix\epsilon } |\epsilon|^{\gamma} \hat{f(\epsilon)}d\epsilon$ then $\|D^\gamma _x e^{it\Delta}u_0\|_{L^q_x(L^2_t)}\leq C\|u_0\|_{L^2}$

$b)$ $\|D^\gamma _x e^{it\Delta}u_0\|_{B^*_{1/2}(L^2)}\leq C\|u_0\|_{L^2}$

And this is know as Strichartz Estimate for the Schrodinger equation. I know this was proved by Strichartz and also by Thao for more general family of functions but  the way to do this with polar coordinates is writing $D^{\gamma}_xe^{it\Delta}u_0(x)=\int e^{ix\epsilon} e^{it|\epsilon|^2}|\epsilon|^{\gamma} \hat{u_0}(\epsilon)d\epsilon $ and then writing this in polar coordinates. I dont know how to apply polar coordinates in this step $(r,\theta)$ would it be just:

$\int e^{ix\cdot (rcos(\theta),rsen(\theta))} e^{it|r|^2}r^{\gamma} \hat{u_0}(r,\theta)rdr d\theta $ but then changing the variable $s=r^2$ would difficult me the sinus and cosinus terms... so I think I am doing something wrong.

Then I have to use Plancherel in $t$ and then Minkowski integral inequality but I dont know how to follow from here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: - What is $B^*_{1/2}$ ?
Remark: $D^\gamma$ is more referred to as the fractional Laplacian than the fractional derivative (since there is the absolute value in the symbol)
- Is $x$ two dimensional ?

Comment: Is the dual of the Besov Space equiped with the norm $\|v\|^2 _{B^*_{1/2}}=sup_j R_j^{-1}\int_{\Omega_j}|v|^2 dx$ and $R^j = 2^{j-1}$and yes $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. And in all papers that I ve read fractional Laplacian was $(-\Delta)^s$ but its the fractional derivative.

Comment: Yes, the fractional Laplacian is exactly defined by your formula
$$
(-\Delta)^{\gamma/2} f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i\,x\cdot y}\,|y|^\gamma \hat{f}(y)\,\mathrm{d}y
$$

Comment: Do you know how to do the change of variable in this estimate and follow from it? Thanks